# Show nested list using seperate component

Tags: vue.js

I have my main page file called Scan.vue where I display a list with object. I don't know how many child objects a parent object has so I want to call another component called ScanList to display that info.

Scan:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-layout class="scanContainer">
      <div class="scanSearch">
        <input
          type="text"
          v-model="search"
          placeholder="Rechercher une localisation :"
        />
      </div>
      <v-list>
        <v-list-group
          v-for="item in items"
          v-bind:key="item"
          v-model="item.active"
        >
          <v-list-tile slot="activator" @click="">
            <v-list-tile-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-tile-title>
          </v-list-tile>
          <ScanList></ScanList>
        </v-list-group>
      </v-list>
    </v-layout>
  </div>
</template>

    <script>
import ScanList from "@/components/scan";
export default {
  components: ScanList,
  data: () => ({
    items: [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: "Location 1",
        subItem: [
          {
          id: 1,
          title: "Row 1",
          qrCode: [
            { id: 1, title: "QR Code"}
          ]
          },
          { id: 2, title: "Row 2" },
          { id: 3, title: "Row 3" },
          { id: 4, title: "Row 4" }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: "Location 2",
        subItem: [
          { id: 1, title: "Row 1" },
          {
            id: 2,
            title: "Row 2",
            qrCode: [
            { id: 2, title: "QR Code" }
          ]
          },
          { id: 3, title: "Row 3" },
          { id: 4, title: "Row 4"}
        ]
      }
    ]
  }),
  props: ["subItems"],
  name: "Scan",
  methods: {
    showSelected(subItems) {
      this.subItems = subItems;
      this.items = true;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Here is the component I created called ScanList:

```
<template>
  <v-list>
    <v-list-group
      v-for="subItem in item.subItem"
      v-bind:key="subItem"
      v-model="subItem.active"
    >
      <v-list-tile slot="activator" @click="">
        <v-list-tile-title>{{ subItem.title }}</v-list-tile-title>
      </v-list-tile>
      <v-list
        v-for="qrCode in subItem.qrCode"
        v-bind:key="qrCode"
        v-model="qrCode.active"
      >
        <v-list-tile>
          <v-list-tile-title>{{ qrCode.title }}</v-list-tile-title>
        </v-list-tile>
      </v-list>
    </v-list-group>
  </v-list>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "ScanList"
};
</script>
```

Nothing is showing up and I'm not sure why. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: `components` should be an object. Try this: `components: { ScanList },`

Comment: Didn't change anything. if I take the code from ScanList and add it to Scan it works but I need to switch the Scan template for the ScanList template when one location is clicked. Sorry I must have a lot more errors I'm really new to all this.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the browser console?

Comment: [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <ScanList>
My component is registered tho...
I have a index.js with import ScanList from "./ScanList"; export { ScanList }; in folder scan with ScanList.vue

Comment: Are you running this through any bundler? (ie. WebPack, Browserify, etc.)

Comment: Is "vue-template-compiler" a bundler? I didn't start the project. First time digging into someone else's code. Just about to go insane...